# solr lucene - how boost bf is applied using edismax. is it additive?

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a query that looks like this:

```
qt=/solrSearchHandler&q={!func}sum(0,0)&bf=someFloatField^1
```

Where a document has `someFloatField` of value 1.

I am using solr.SearchHandler request handler w/ edismax defType.

I'm trying to figure out why the score for a document is not the sum of the bf/boost and the function query value (specified as q).

In this example I expect the score to be 1 `(sum(0,0) + boost weight=1 * someFloatField=1)` but it is actually 0. After playing w/ the numbers I see that the score is actually being calculated as:

```
q + bf * q
```

instead of

```
q + bf
```

which is what I expected for additive boosting. Perhaps I am confused about how boosts are a incorporated into the score. If so, I would appreciate any direction as to how to simply add the 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

According to the wiki, the bf parameter is additive.  If you need multiplicative, use the boost parameter instead.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#bf_.28Boost_Function.2C_additive.29

The bf parameter stands for "boost function" but the value you've indicated looks like you're treating it as "boost field" instead.  If you need to use the value of that field to calculate your boost, you can do so in a function query, which is what the bf is expecting:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery

If I am reading that right, the 'def' function might be what you need, possibly in a more complex overall function.  I could be misunderstanding all this, though.

Comment: I expected bf to be additive but in my case it does not just add the bf value, it adds (bf * q) where q is the function query score.